# How to get the number of CPU cycles used by a process

Tags: c#, vb.net, performance, process, performancecounter

I have a need to get the number of CPU cycles used by a specific process using C# (or VB.Net).  This information is available in the Process properties popup within Sysinternal's Process Explorer.  For instance, the browser that I'm using the post this message has currently used 18,521,360,165 cyles (give or take a few hundred million).  Does anyone know how to get this information from a .Net app?  I know how to get the CPU usage (percentage), but this isn't what I'm looking for.  I need a way to compare CPU usage between two different processes running at different times.

Thank you,
Matt

**Update:**
Why do I need this?  I'm the leader of the local .Net user group and we're running a code challenge where developers submit code to solve a problem.  I need a way to measure the performance of one entry against another.  Currently I'm using a timer to measure performance.  The server is 100% dedicated to this, but that doesn't guarantee that something else might be happening at the same time.  Obviously, this is frought with all kinds of potential issues, but generally speaking, it's fairly accurate.  Measuring the number of CPU cycles used would be an almost fool proof way to measure how well someone's entry performs against another.  I'm certain that someone can shoot holes all over this - no need to try at this point.  ;-)  I hope that helps explain the reason behind my question and why a timer is insufficient for solving my problem.

Comment: Would that be the CPU cycles including or excluding the counting of CPU cycles?

Comment: Ideally I would be doing the counting from a different process, so hopefully excluding, but including is fine too.  I just need the relative difference between two runs of the same process (given different input)

Comment: I would be very curious to know why you're interested in the number of cycles. For profiling purposes, timing down to the millisecond is usually sufficient.

Comment: @Charlie Salts : Usually but not always -- the programs I work on have an upper limit on their main loop of 16.6ms, so the functions I need to profile are all on the order of micro and nanoseconds.

Comment: @Charlie: just using a StopWatch measures wall-clock time. No way of telling how long the scheduler lets you have the CPU during that time.

Comment: Have you looked at Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks?

Comment: @dbasne: same problem as with milliseconds.

Comment: @dbasnett: I'm currently using a StopWatch, but as has been said, I can't be sure that something else wasn't happening on the system at the same time in a different process that would cause the time to be exagerated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Process Explorer calls [`QueryProcessCycleTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684929.aspx) to get that information. You will probably have to use P/Invoke to call it. I would expect its P/Invoke signature to look like:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool QueryProcessCycleTime(IntPtr ProcessHandle, out ulong CycleTime);
```

Comment: This looks promising!  Thank you!

Comment: I just tried this and it appears to work flawlessly!  Awesome.  Thank you, Gabe.

Comment: @Matt: You might consider using `QueryThreadCycleTime` too, to isolate just the thread you're interested in.

Comment: Nice, I'll give that a try too.  Thank you!

Comment: Here's an example of the use of `QueryThreadCycleTime` and `QueryProcessCycleTime`: https://gist.github.com/zhangz/6094657

Comment: I am trying to write a program that tests efficiency in c# just like OP. Obviously this answer worked for him, but how do you actually implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to query the performance counters inside the CPUs. This is low level and very hardware specific, so you'll have to thunk to native code to get it. [PAPI](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/overview/index.html) is the closest thing to a portable library for this task.

Be aware that context switches can change many of these internal CPU registers, so you'll need to do this query from inside your process. Querying the CPU counters from a different process will give you spurious results.

Remember also that CPU cycle count is not the same as (and on the x86, isn't even similar to) "number of instructions performed."

Comment: OP wants to query the performance counters maintained by the OS, not determine them himself.

Comment: @Gabe:  Yes, a perf counter would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

There is a CodeProject article here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/processescpuusage.aspx

I think this article will help you do exactly what you are trying to do. Basically they show you 2 ways to do it, one using the managed System.Diagnostics tools and the second using a Win API method call.

Comment: As I said in the question, knowing the CPU usage percetage is not what I'm looking for, rather, I need to know the number of cycles the CPU has used for a specific process.