# How to measure CPU cycles of a given process in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, cpu-usage

I have some different models that perform the same task, using different algorithms. I want to compare the performance of these models by measuring CPU cycles (I tried using `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch` to count Ticks, but the result is not accurate enough).

I have found a [class](https://gist.github.com/zhangz/6094657) that measures CPU cycles by using `P/Invoke`, as follows:

```
IModel model;
CodeTimer.Time(true, model.ToString(), totalTime, model.TimeStep);
```

The method above iterates by `N` times the method `model.TimeStep`. I noticed that the results of `CodeTimer.Time` vary greatly (by at least one order of magnitude, from `58 KCycles` to `890 KCycles`). Thus, correct me if I am wrong, but as `CodeTimer` class marks the cycles before and after the process, it can also count the cycles used by any other processes (even OS processes) occurring during the execution of `model.TimeStep` method (the method which I want to measure performance).

So two questions:

1. Is my above supposition correct? If it is, then I need to come up with another solution to measure CPU cycles, which leads to my main question:

I then came up with the idea of iterating `model.TimeStep()` in a different `System.Threading.Thread` and measuring the cycles of the given thread using [`QueryProcessCycleTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684929.aspx). However as `QueryProcessCycleTime` receives as input a `System.Threading.WaitHandle` (or an `IntPtr` as well), I don't know how to tell this method that I want to measure the cycles of that specific `Thread` I just created. In another words, I don't know how to put together the `thread` which I create to iterate the model, the `WaitHandle` and the `QueryProcessCycleTime`, even though I have read some [examples](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/waithandles.shtml) of using `WaitHandle` (I just can't mix everything together).

2. How can I accomplish that?

It would be something like this:

```
class ModelSimulator
{
    public Model1 model1 { get; private set; } // implements IModel
    public Model2 model2 { get; private set; } // implements IModel

/* other methods */

    public void RunModel(object obj)
    {
        IModel model = (IModel)obj;
        Int32 t = model.maxTime;
        while (t-- > 0)
            model.TimeStep();
    }
}
```

And inside the `main` method, I do:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern Boolean QueryProcessCycleTime(SafeWaitHandle processHandle, out UInt64 CycleTime);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ModelSimulator ms = new ModelSimulator();
    Thread thread = new Thread(ms.RunModel);
    thread.Start(ms.model1);
    // here I start the thread, but how can I use QueryProcessCycleTime to measure
    // the thread execution
}
```

PS: mine is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526828/how-to-get-the-number-of-cpu-cycles-used-by-a-process), because I need some more specific answer, which is not there... My question could be a complement to that question.

Comment: Why don't you just execute your calculations 100000 times and compare the results based on that?

Comment: I do that already, and I use the `Ticks` to measure the time of `N` iterations of `model.TimeStep()`. But the results are very inconclusive. One option is to increase `N`, such that I get a significant number of `Ticks` for each of my samples. But I suppose that counting cycles is more accurate. Isn't it?

Comment: some models have a very fast execution of `model.TimeStep()` (~ 1 nano-second) whereas other have a very slow execution of it (~ 79 ns). The accuracy of Ticks is 1 mili-second = 10000 Ticks in windows, so its accuracy is actually 100 nano-seconds, but I need something which runs in only a few nano-seconds.

Comment: Yuo go to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684929.aspx), and read about QueryProcessCycleTime. Then you realize that that function "Retrieves the sum of the cycle time of **all threads** of the specified process". Then you continue to read MSDN, until you reach the _See also_ part... There you find a link to a function called [QueryThreadCycleTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684943.aspx) which "Retrieves the cycle time for the specified thread".

Comment: This looks like an X-Y problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the actual business requirement you are trying to solve?

Comment: If you really need *real-time* performance then Windows, never mind DOT NET, is an inappropriate tool for the task. (1) Windows is a pre-emptive time-sharing OS, not a real-time OS; (2) The DOT NET GC will interfere with your response because it runs non-deterministically.

Comment: Then, if 100000 isn't enough measure over 100000000 iterations or something like that. Like @Pieter said, if one of your models has more GC pressure than another, your results will not be conclusive enough on a small number of iterations.

Comment: @Shlomi Borovitz but how would I get a `WaitHandle` from a `System.Threading.Thread`?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I don't care about "real world" performance, but I care about relative performance between the models

Comment: @Girardi First, I seriously suggest that you'll follow the suggestion above me. Measure execution's time for a high number of iterations. But if you insist, then you can call the unmanaged function [GetCurrentThread ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683182.aspx)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: If I had tried anything to solve the question I am posing, I generally write about it in the question... I am not trying to solve a "business" requirement, as I am just trying to measure performance of some ODE solvers for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @ShlomiBorovitz, one can use [`GetCurrentThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683182.aspx) in order to identify the `Thread` which is running the process. The possible solution is a very simple modification in the [`CodeTimer.cs`](https://gist.github.com/zhangz/6094657). The modification needed may be found in the end of this answer. I added a class named `PerformanceStatus` to have the amount of Garbage Collection for levels 0, 1 and 2 as well in the result of the `CodeTimer.Time()` method used to measure performance. Thus, one can also know whether the Garbage Collector had collected anything during the process.

You then just need to use it like:

```
ModelSimulator nm = new ModelSimulator();
CodeTimer c = new CodeTimer(nm.RunModel, model); // model implements IModel
UInt64 time = c.Time().CPUCycles;
Console.WriteLine("{0:0.000e+000} KCy", (Double)time / 1000.0D);
```

Such that the class `ModelSimulator` is given in the question, bearing a method `ModelSimulator.RunModel(IModel model)` which receives an object of type `IModel`.

Here is the `CodeTimer.cs` needed to measure the performance

```
public sealed class CycleTime
{
    private Boolean m_trackingThreadTime;
    private SafeWaitHandle m_handle;
    private UInt64 m_startCycleTime;

    private CycleTime(Boolean trackingThreadTime, SafeWaitHandle handle)
    {
        m_trackingThreadTime = trackingThreadTime;
        m_handle = handle;
        m_startCycleTime = m_trackingThreadTime ? Thread() : Process(m_handle);
    }

    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public UInt64 Elapsed()
    {
        UInt64 now = m_trackingThreadTime ? Thread(/*m_handle*/) : Process(m_handle);
        return now - m_startCycleTime;
    }

    public static CycleTime StartThread(SafeWaitHandle threadHandle)
    {
        return new CycleTime(true, threadHandle);
    }

    public static CycleTime StartProcess(SafeWaitHandle processHandle)
    {
        return new CycleTime(false, processHandle);
    }

    public static UInt64 Thread(IntPtr threadHandle)
    {
        UInt64 cycleTime;
        if (!QueryThreadCycleTime(threadHandle, out cycleTime))
            throw new Win32Exception();
        return cycleTime;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the cycle time for the specified thread.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="threadHandle">Identifies the thread whose cycle time you'd like to obtain.</param>
    /// <returns>The thread's cycle time.</returns>
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public static UInt64 Thread(SafeWaitHandle threadHandle)
    {
        UInt64 cycleTime;
        if (!QueryThreadCycleTime(threadHandle, out cycleTime))
            throw new Win32Exception();
        return cycleTime;
    }

    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public static UInt64 Thread()
    {
        UInt64 cycleTime;
        if (!QueryThreadCycleTime((IntPtr)(-2), out cycleTime))
            throw new Win32Exception();
        return cycleTime;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the sum of the cycle time of all threads of the specified process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="processHandle">Identifies the process whose threads' cycles times you'd like to obtain.</param>
    /// <returns>The process' cycle time.</returns>
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public static UInt64 Process(SafeWaitHandle processHandle)
    {
        UInt64 cycleTime;
        if (!QueryProcessCycleTime(processHandle, out cycleTime))
            throw new Win32Exception();
        return cycleTime;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the cycle time for the idle thread of each processor in the system.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The number of CPU clock cycles used by each idle thread.</returns>
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public static UInt64[] IdleProcessors()
    {
        Int32 byteCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        UInt64[] cycleTimes = new UInt64[byteCount];
        byteCount *= 8;   // Size of UInt64
        if (!QueryIdleProcessorCycleTime(ref byteCount, cycleTimes))
            throw new Win32Exception();
        return cycleTimes;
    }

    [DllImport("Kernel32", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern Boolean QueryThreadCycleTime(IntPtr threadHandle, out UInt64 CycleTime);

    [DllImport("Kernel32", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern Boolean QueryThreadCycleTime(SafeWaitHandle threadHandle, out UInt64 CycleTime);

    [DllImport("Kernel32", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern Boolean QueryProcessCycleTime(SafeWaitHandle processHandle, out UInt64 CycleTime);

    [DllImport("Kernel32", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern Boolean QueryIdleProcessorCycleTime(ref Int32 byteCount, UInt64[] CycleTimes);

    [DllImport("Kernel32", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetCurrentThread();
}

public sealed class CodeTimer //: IDisposable
{
    private Int32 m_collectionCount0;
    private Int32 m_collectionCount1;
    private Int32 m_collectionCount2;

    private Thread m_thread;
    private IModel m_model;
    private Action<IModel> m_performanceMethod;

    private UInt64 outThreadCycles;

    public CodeTimer(Action<IModel> perfMethod, IModel model)
    {
        PrepareForOperation();

        m_performanceMethod = perfMethod;
        m_model = model;
        m_thread = new Thread(PerformanceTest);
    }

    private void PerformanceTest()
    {
        PrepareForOperation();
        IntPtr p = CycleTime.GetCurrentThread();
        UInt64 t = CycleTime.Thread(p);
        m_performanceMethod(m_model);
        outThreadCycles = CycleTime.Thread(p) - t;
    }

    public PerformanceStatus Time()
    {
        m_thread.Start();
        m_thread.Join();
        return new PerformanceStatus(GC.CollectionCount(0) - m_collectionCount0, GC.CollectionCount(1) - m_collectionCount1, GC.CollectionCount(2) - m_collectionCount2, outThreadCycles);
    }

    private void PrepareForOperation()
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        m_collectionCount0 = GC.CollectionCount(0);
        m_collectionCount1 = GC.CollectionCount(1);
        m_collectionCount2 = GC.CollectionCount(2);
    }
}

public class PerformanceStatus
{
    public Int32 GCCount1;
    public Int32 GCCount2;
    public Int32 GCCount3;
    public UInt64 CPUCycles;
    public PerformanceStatus(Int32 gc1, Int32 gc2, Int32 gc3, UInt64 cpuCycles)
    {
        this.GCCount1 = gc1;
        this.GCCount2 = gc2;
        this.GCCount3 = gc3;
        this.CPUCycles = cpuCycles;
    }
}
```